# Issue with W3CCapabilities in geckodriver

Tags: ruby, watir

I have an issue while adding custom capabilities to my browser. Right now I use next code:

```
capabilities = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::W3CCapabilities.firefox(accept_insecure_certs: true)
b = Watir::Browser.new( :firefox, :desired_capabilities => capabilities)
```

This code outputs a deprecation warning:

```
2017-07-18 16:13:05 WARN Selenium [DEPRECATION] Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::W3CCapabilities is deprecated. Use Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities instead.
```

But when I try to use Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities as suggested, project fails with:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::SessionNotCreatedError: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities
```

I need the capabilities to ignore unsigned certificates warning, how do I get rid of this deprecation warning?

Comment: Please use legacy firefox driver, geckodriver has many problem.